# Can I use Ninject insted of PRISM? or maybe it sould replace Unity in PRISM?

Tags: c#, unity-container, prism, mef, ninject

I'm going to start an pretty large project witch contains 30+ modules, I have goggled almost for a  capable framework ? Need some help to find out witch one of these is soutable?

1) PRISM
2) Ninject
3) Unity or MEF

any why?
I'm using MVVM in WPF4.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most appropriate framework will depend on the problems that you are trying to solve.  There is nothing to stop you using more than one of these frameworks together if it is appropriate, they are not mutually exclusive.

For example, we started a large scale enterprise composite app and used Prism, then we started to use MEF and slowly phased out Prism as it wasn't necessary to meet any of the business requirements. So now we use a mixture of Unity for our app's main DI infrastructure, and MEF for dynamic discovery of plugins.

I would also strongly recommend looking at something like [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) for simplifying MVVM.

Comment: Thank , it changed my mind against the techniques, and the Caliburn.Micro was a good idea I'll check that too. but still i have no idea about the Ninject !!!

Comment: Ninject is a very nice IoC container, and there would be no reason not to check it out over something like Unity or Castle Windsor. All of these IoC containers would be good choices for your DI infrastructure, but it will depend on the exact features you will require, and which API you would prefer to work with.

Comment: sometimes it just comes down to personal preference.  I prefer Ninject because it's very lightweight and simple.

Comment: To bring this answer up to date a bit, Prism now separates its MVVM implementation, providing some nice toys that can be used totally separate from the application framework. This includes viewmodel discovery and the event aggregator. Prism also includes many features that an IoC container does not, but it is a client framework first and foremost. Not using WPF? Don't bother with prism.

Comment: Stylet does further evolve down the road Caliburn.Micro had started. Stone cold seemless dependency injection => https://github.com/canton7/Stylet